# Column split into two separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to split my *Period* column into two different column. First will be quarter and second will be its corresponding year.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Period': ["Q3'16", "Q1'17", "Q2'17","Q3'17"]})
```

dtype: Object

Result should look like this:

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'Quarter': ['Q3', 'Q1', 'Q2','Q3'],
'Year': ['2016','2017','2017','2017']})
```

Since this doesn't belong to any timestamp format. I am having some difficulties figuring this out.

For reference my original df looks like this. And the column is object type.
[image: For reference my original df looks like this]

Comment: The code you provided has some mistakes in it. First of all, creating the dataframe like that will result in an error because you should be using double quotation marks for the periods since you have the ' character within the string.

Comment: Yes rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with convert periods to datetimes and extract `year`:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'].replace(r"(Q\d)'(\d+)", r'\2-\1', regex=True))

df['Quarter'] = df['Period'].str.extract(r"(Q\d)")
df['Year']  = dates.dt.strftime('%Y')
```

---

Or if all years are greater like `2000` use `str.extract`:

```
df['Quarter'] = df['Period'].str.extract(r"(Q\d)")
df['Year']  = '20' + df['Period'].str.extract(r"'(\d+)")
```

Or solution with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
s = df['Period'].str.split("'")
df['Quarter'] = s.str[0]
df['Year']  = '20' + s.str[1]
```

Alternative:

```
df[['Quarter','Year']] = df['Period'].str.split("'", expand=True)
df['Year']  = '20' + df['Year']
```

---

```
print (df)
  Period Quarter  Year
0  Q3'16      Q3  2016
1  Q1'17      Q1  2017
2  Q2'17      Q2  2017
3  Q3'17      Q3  2017
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Period': ["Q3'16", "Q1'17", "Q2'17","Q3'17"]})
df = pd.DataFrame(df.Period.str.split("'",1).tolist(),
                             columns = ['Quarter','Year'])
df["Year"] = "20"+df["Year"] 
print(df)
```